# how can I print this symbol in PyCharm: "█"

Tags: ascii, python-3.7

I'm trying to print = " █ "
in PyCharm. I get not exception thrown, or TraceBack error.
but instead of printing " █ " it prints " ? ".
how can I make PyCharm to print the symbol ?
it's ASCII code is 219

Comment: Does it work if you enter the proper Unicode code instead of a literal character (it's not an ASCII character)?

Comment: nope, just some fancy question marks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
>>> print('\u2588')
█
```

I checked it in pycharm as well, it works.